# OpenGL ES - Pixel 'Interference' at bottom of texture

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, texture2d

I'm loading an int* array of RGBA pixel data from a UIImage, doing manipulation on it, then setting the pixels to a Glubyte* texture buffer and writing them to the texture with

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texBuffer);
```

This works fine, however I get some weird pixelation "interference" at the bottom of the screen.

Anyone have any idea what might be causing this effect?

EDIT: Solved this myself, see my answer

Comment: How do you allocate texBuffer? Try allocate texWidth*texHeight*4 bytes and fill the memory with zeros. Still interference? If not then your existing allocation is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was in the int* buffer declaration, it should have been:

```
int* pixelArray = malloc(4*w*h);
```